# Selecting number of days within one column by group in SAS

Tags: sql, date, sas, proc

I am trying to identify the IDs that had three or more services performed within a 90-day period. 
I have columns: service date, ID, service,  and other types of demographic info. 
Could you please help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add:
Sample data,
Your solution/try, and a sample for the desired result.

Comment: Are you looking for IDs with 3 different types of services, or are repeats of the same one ok?

Comment: Repeats are ok. I am having a hard time selecting a 90-day interval for each ID, because the dates are scattered over one year for each ID.

Comment: 3 services on the same date counts as 3 rather than 1 I presume?

Comment: Yes, each service needs to be counted. Thank you.

Comment: Code added - see if it works with your data. If it does, please could you upvote and accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of one possible solution:

- Sort your dataset by ID and date
- For each ID, work through all services in sequence, using lag / retain / dow-loop to compare the dates of the 2 previous services to the current one.
- If both differences are less than 90 days then output that ID.

This might give you some IDs more than once, but you can easily get rid of any duplicates with a second pass, or by skipping to the next ID if the current one is output.

Here's a stab at this using a [DOW-loop](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/038-2009.pdf) - I think this does what you want for the example data I've used below. Let me know if you find any cases where it doesn't work as expected.

```
data have;
  format service_date date9.;
  informat id 8. service_date date9. service $1.;
  input id service_date service;
  datalines;
1 01jan2013 a
1 01feb2013 b
1 14feb2013 c
1 15feb2013 d
2 01mar2013 a
2 01mar2013 a
2 01oct2013 a
2 01oct2013 a
;
run;

data want;
  array dates[3];
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.ID);
    set have;
    by ID;
    dates[mod(_n_,3)+1] = service_date;
    if _n_ >= 3 then do;
      if intnx('month', dates[mod(_n_,3)+1],-3) <= min(dates[mod(_n_-1,3)+1], dates[mod(_n_-2,3)+1]) then do;
        output;
        delete;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

I seem to have inadvertently set this up to spot instances where you have 3 or more services within a 3-month period rather than a 90-day period, but that can easily be changed.

Comment: Could you share an example of the SAS code for the steps (Except proc sort)? Thank you.

Comment: I am having a little problem with this code. If I run it as it is then the output doesn't display the row:"1 15feb2013 d". It only displays: 1 14feb2013 c. But in my case I would need to see both rows. Could you help in getting this result?

Comment: I thought you only wanted each ID once if it met your criteria at any point throughout the year, which is what the above does. If you want every service that's the last one in a group of 3 for the same ID within a 3-month period, then change it from `output; delete;` to just `output;`.

Comment: Better yet, follow Peter's suggestion from earlier, and provide some example input and output data, so there is no ambiguity about what you want. Use the example data I posted as a template.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it does what I wanted. I will post a question an example next time. I appreciate your help.